# Can I make running `zfs receive` without "-s" to save receive_resume_token by signal?

Tags: zfs

I am running a zfs send/receive. However I forget to set `zfs receive -s`.

Is this possible to inform a running `zfs receive` to save receive_resume_token by a signal sends from `kill -s`  ?

Or is there other way to save a checkpoint ?

Comment: Please consider Syncoid: https://github.com/jimsalterjrs/sanoid/blob/master/syncoid